# ELF file OS ABI invalid

Tags: linux, build, openmpi

I am recently doing some experiment on building a cluster system for computing tasks. My server is Suse Linux Enterprise 11, and one of the client is Redhat Enterprise Linux 5. I compiled openmpi on Suse, and it runs fine alone. Then I shared /usr/local(where the openmpi was installed) to my Redhat client, and tried to do mpirun, the following error popped up: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/local/openmpi/lib/libopen-rte.so.0: ELF file OS ABI invalid. Does this mean that I have to compile openmpi on redhat separately? Thanks!

Comment: Does it happen by chance that your SuSE installation is 64-bit while the RedHat one is 32-bit?